# FactoryBoy / Django - handling constants

Tags: django, factory

I am creating a factory for the following Django model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey('elearning.Tenant')
    book_id = models.IntegerField()
    ean = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="titel", max_length=200)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price_id = models.IntegerField()
    buy_option_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    loan_days = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    type = 'Yindoboek'
```

Which I turned into this factory:

```
class BookFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    tenant = factory.SubFactory(TenantFactory)
    book_id = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: random.randint(1, 1000))
    ean = factory.LazyFunction(
        lambda: ''.join(
            random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(6)
        ) + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(6))
    )
    title = factory.Faker('company')
    author_name = factory.Faker('name_male')
    description = factory.Faker('text')
    price_id = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: random.randint(1, 1000))
    buy_option_text = factory.Faker('sentence')
    loan_days = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: random.randint(1, 150))
    type = 'Yindoboek'
```

However, when I try to run the following test:

```
    def test_factory_matches_model(self):
        """ Verify that the factory generates a valid Book instance """
        self.assertTrue(self.book)
        self.assertTrue(self.book.tenant)
```

It crashes with the following error:

`TypeError: 'type' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

FactoryBoy seems to be tripping of the `type` 'field' within the `Book` model, which is not a Django field instance but a constant.

If I exclude this field from the factory the test will pass - but I'd rather not remove fields (the whole point is to test all fields / combinations) - so I was wondering if there was a way around this problem, does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

As per the [documentation](http://TypeError:%20'type'%20is%20an%20invalid%20keyword%20argument%20for%20this%20function) the non-field parameters should be put in a separate `Params` class.

To working model looks like this:

```
class BookFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    tenant = factory.SubFactory(TenantFactory)
    book_id = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: random.randint(1, 1000))
    ean = factory.LazyFunction(
        lambda: ''.join(
            random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(6)
        ) + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(6))
    )
    title = factory.Faker('company')
    author_name = factory.Faker('name_male')
    description = factory.Faker('text')
    price_id = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: random.randint(1, 1000))
    buy_option_text = factory.Faker('sentence')
    loan_days = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: random.randint(1, 150))

    class Params:
        type = 'Yindoboek'
```